# How to remove whitespace after ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_MODIFIED and the like

Tags: oh-my-zsh

So currently I have this as my `ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT` stuff:

```
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_PREFIX="[ "
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SUFFIX=" ] "
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_DIRTY=" ✘"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_CLEAN=" ✔"

ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_ADDED="✚"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_MODIFIED="★"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_DELETED="✖"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_RENAMED="➜"
```

My problem is that the `ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_DIRTY` and `ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_CLEAN` always add a trailing white space.

Meaning that from the above if I have a clean git project, it looks like this: `[ master ✔  ]`

And if I have a dirty git project, it looks like this: `[ master ✘ ★ ]`

As you can see, the clean version has 2 spaces after because I add a space on the SUFFIX for when it is dirty, so I was wondering if there was a way to remove the automatically added space on the CLEAN/DIRTY git prompts so I can alleviate this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SUFFIX` has space as the first character.

```
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SUFFIX=" ] "
```

The line above should be like this:

```
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SUFFIX="] "
```

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. I meant in the first one with just the master, there's 2 spaces, but on the 2nd one there's only one space. I only ever want there to be one space, regardless of which one it is. I need the space there for the 2nd one to have a space between the ] and the star.